# Align all items horizontally to the left with CSS grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

1. I have an unknown number of items and I want them stacked horizontally to the left
2. I want a fixed gap between the items
3. The width of the items is unknown, and could have variations

I know I could use `flex` like below, but I'd like to know if this accomplishable with `grid`.

```css
#box { 
  display: flex; 
  width: 300px; 
  outline: 1px solid blue; 
}
.item { 
  background: gray; 
  width: 50px; 
  height: 100px; 
}

#box > * + * {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id='box'>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
</div>
```

### Update

Increased the width value for the parent, to display clearer what I'm going after - the children should not take up the full parent width (unless there are many children of course).

Comment: Please supply some HTML and at least an attempt at doing this yourself.

Comment: Change to `display:grid;` and add `grid-auto-flow:column;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here. I used the same measures and sizes from your example.

Depends on children width

```css
#box {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  column-gap: 10px;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}

.item {
  background: gray;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id='box'>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
</div>
```

Depends on parent width

```css
#box {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  column-gap: 10px;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  width: 230px;
}

.item {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id='box'>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
</div>
```

**UPDATED**

Wen the size of parent is 100% width and number of children is indefinite.

```css
#box {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 50px);
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  column-gap: 10px;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}

.item {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id='box'>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
</div>
```

Now we know, your case can be solved with `grid`, but I suggest you to use `flex`. Using `grid` for this task is like hitting a screw with a hammer - we can reach a goal, but using wrong tool. `Grid` is more useful for tables with unusual pattern of sells, better if we know the number of columns. And `Flex` more useful for lists of elements, like in your case. Although `Flex` is older and more native then `Grid`, works a lot more stable in all modern browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, have updated the question with info about the leftover spacing of the parent.